# Show that two Linear Programming problems are equal

Tags: linear-programming

Consider the general linear programming problem

> $min \sum_{j=1}^n c_jx_j$
>
> s.t. $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j \leq b_i$, for $i=1,\dots , m$
>
> $x_j \geq 0$ for $j=1,\dots , n$

And the corresponding extended formulation

> $min \sum_{j=1}^n c_jx_j$
>
> s.t. $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j + x_{n+i} = b_i$ for $i=1,\dots m$
>
> $x_j\geq 0$ for $j=1,\dots,m+n$.

Show that both problems are equivalent. Hint: two problems $[A]$ and $[B]$ are equivelent if for each feasible solution of $[A]$ there is a corresponding feasible solution of $[B]$ with the same objective value and vice versa.

---

Being a feasible solution of $A$ means that all constraints of $A$ should be satisfied. However, I cannot seem to find a way to show that then all constraints of $B$ should also be satisfied. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: @copper.hat My bad, I made a typo. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In extended form the inequality constraints in first case can be written as
$$a_{1,1}x_1+a_{1,2}x_2+...+a_{1,n}x_n\le b_1$$
$$a_{2,1}x_1+a_{2,2}x_2+...+a_{2,n}x_n\le b_2$$
$$...$$
$$a_{m,1}x_1+a_{m,2}x_2+...+a_{m,n}x_n\le b_m$$
Let's introduce some slack variables $x_{n+i}\ge 0$ into the inequality constraints such that
$$a_{1,1}x_1+a_{1,2}x_2+...+a_{1,n}x_n+x_{n+1}= b_1$$
$$a_{2,1}x_1+a_{2,2}x_2+...+a_{2,n}x_n+x_{n+2}= b_2$$
$$...$$
$$a_{m,1}x_1+a_{m,2}x_2+...+a_{m,n}x_n+x_{n+m}= b_m$$
In short form
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{i,j}x_j+x_{n+i}=b_i\quad for\,i=1,...,m$$
And the first case is transformed into the second one

------EDIT-------

We can rewrite the equality conditions in B such as
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{i,j}x_j=b_i-x_{n+i}\quad for\,i=1,...,m$$
Since the question states that $x_j\ge 0$ for $j=1,...,m+n$ we can eliminate $x_j$ for $j> n$ by using inequality constraints without loss of generality such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{i,j}x_j\le b_i\quad for\,i=1,...,m$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand the concept of using slack variables, however, how does this show that every solution of the first problem is also a solution of the second problem with the same objective value?

Comment: Because that makes both cases perfectly identical. If you want a more solid proof you can google "Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions".

Comment: Ok :). By the way, isn't the proof in reverse order (so from B to A) exaclty identical (but then in the opposite direction) to this one?

Comment: Actually no. Because A is more general. Equality constraints are special case in convex optimization; no need for complementary slackness conditions. Therefore it is more rigid to derive the special case from general case.

Comment: But then how do I show the reverse proof? Because the question asks me to show that it also holds 'vice versa'so from B to A.

Comment: Check my edit for inverse transformation

Comment: @cruise any time...